# Create dictionary from panda series with multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a pd dataframe as follow:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['A',1],['A',3],['B',2],['B',5],['C',8]],columns=['k','v'])
```

And from I would like to create the following dictionary:

```
{'A':[1,3],
 'B':[2,5],
 'C':[8]
}
```

I am currently doing it with:

```
from collections import defaultdict


my_dict=defaultdict(list)

for key in df.k:
    my_dict[key].append(df['v'][df['k']==key])
```

But it is not efficient (very time consuming) for large df and also sends me back the index of the values, which I do not want.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with `pd.to_dict`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: It does not do the groupby on each key, so I would have twice the same key with distinct values for each.

Comment: @PaulJ. You're correct that it wouldn't group each key together, but dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, so you would simply lose everything but the last value for each key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `agg` here:

```
df.groupby('k').v.agg(list).to_dict()
```

```
{'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2, 5], 'C': [8]}
```